# Fragment arguments contains NO data after retrieving from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

So, I have a fragment - fragment A - which contains an object - object O - used for setting up TextViews and other elements. To instantiate the fragment I use a static method A.getInstance(O). Object O is serializable so I can send it to the new instance of fragment A through a Bundle by using instance.setArguments and so on.

I retrieve O in the onCreate method of A and setup the fields using O in onViewCreated. Everything works fine until here. After I **replace** A with another fragment - fragment B - and navigate back from B to A, **the arguments Bundle doesn't contain object O anymore** and I get NullPointerException. The Bundle itself is not null, but it doesn't contain O.

I use this method to replace fragments:

```
public void replaceCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

**Fragment A is also displayed using the method above.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you restore object O only from `Fragment#getArgumnets()` ? Did you try to save and restore object O from Fragment instance state?

Comment: I'm saving object O in the instance of fragment A during onCreate. The problem is I don't get O the second time I get in onCreate.

Comment: I mean, did you override Fragment#onSaveInstanceState to save your object, and then look for it in Bundle, passed in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)?

Comment: Nope, I did not do that. Is it necessary? I'm currently retrieving the bundle using Fragment#getArguments(). Shouldn't it return the same Bundle every time?

Answer (score 1):

Notice `Fragment#onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.
When you first created your Fragment from `A#getInstance` method, this passed Bundle will be null. You will just extract your O objects from `Fragment#getArguments` method, like you do. 
In order to save your object for future use, override `Fragment#onSaveInstanceState` and save your O object there (may look like this)

```
private static final String EXTRA_MY_OBJECT = "com.example.extra_my_object";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_MY_OBJECT, mMyObject);
}
```

And then in `Fragment#onCreate` you can grab your object from passed `Bundle`
Just like that:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mMyObject = savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_MY_OBJECT);
    }
    if (mMyObject == null) {
        //fragment was created for first time probably, or something went wrong
        //try to get your object from getArguments

    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, onSaveInstanceState isn't called when I replace the fragment. So, when I navigate back, I face the same issue. 

When the current fragment is replaced, the last lifecycle callback is onStop and onSaveInstanceState is never called until this point. So yeah. . .